# Make Label Align Right Using Bootstrap 4 Modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, label, bootstrap-4

How can I make this label align right? I can only align it left. I have to override the bootstrap 4 default value of `justify-content: center` to `justify-content: right !important;` But it aligns to the left. How can I align it to the right?

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <label class="col-md-4">Type</label>
            <input class="col-md-8" type="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.form-inline label.col-md-4 {
    justify-content: right !important; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change it to:

```
div.form-inline label.col-md-4{
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

`justify-content: right` is not a valid value.

Comment: Thanks. And how can i make the label with the input group align to the center?

Comment: I uploaded a picture. I mean how can i make the space the same on both the "type and "input form" so it looks properly aligned. So it looks even on the left and right side.

Comment: What I would do is to have a smaller width column for the input form. Instead of `.col-md-8` try `.col-md-5` or 6... There is no exact way to do this as the input takes the entire width of the container...

Answer (score 16):

add class "text-right" to label

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Type</label>
            <input class="col-md-8" type="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`justify-content: flex-end` didn't work for me (Bootstrap 4.1.0), but `text-align: right` works:

```
<style>
label { text-align: right }
</style>
```

or in a .css file:

```
.col-form-label { text-align: right }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 shifted to `flex` layout rather than `block`. You have to use `justify-content: flex-end` for your case.

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

```css
div.form-inline label.col-md-4{
  justify-content: flex-end; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-inline">
              <label class="col-md-4">Type</label>
              <input class="col-md-8" type="email" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```